# Addition of two columns in sub query not giving correct result set

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT a, b
FROM dcl 
WHERE a='123'
AND b> (
  SELECT SUM(a) 
         + 
         (SELECT SUM(a) 
          FROM d
          WHERE a= 1506453)
  FROM aslp  
  WHERE a.a= '0527416666')
```

The Output i am getting

```
a=123
b= 23
```

As per the condition i have written in sub query i should not get the above record.

Comment: Why shouldn't you? What should you get then?

Comment: if i execute above query i should not get any result but i am getting  result

Comment: You don't get a result, but you do? Why should it be empty? The question is entirely unclear.

Comment: I think that + symbol is creating problem so i am getting result.

Comment: You still haven't explained **why** you shouldn't get a result from the query. Please edit the question explaining that.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Or, better yet, put up an example on SQL Fiddle.  As written, your question has no basis for anyone else to understand it, because you have provide no basis for determining what should or should not be returned.

Comment: 60.06 > 51.05 + 9.01  condition is false so i should not get any record

Comment: @user4287146 How is anyone supposed to know that the results from the calculations would be 51.05 + 9.01 ?

Comment: I have calculated from my side and i am giving you the result. i think that + symbol is making issue .is there any way to write query with out + symbol.

Comment: @user4287146 If you want anyone to be able to give you an informed answer you need to update the question with table definitions and sample source data that reproduces the error. Without this information all anyone can do is guess.

Comment: Is there any way to over come + symbol problem

Comment: @user4287146 Why do you think the addition is the problem? What does the subquery return if you execute it by itself?

Comment: The problem is not going to be the `+` operator, and as you have said `60.06` is not greater than `51.05 + 9.01` - Therefore one of 3 things is true - **(1)** `eCPClaim_total_claim_charge` is not 60.06,  **(2)** the result of your first subquery is not 51.05, or  **(3)** the result of your second subquery is not 9.01.

Comment: i will get 60.06    so 60.06 > 60.06 is false right i should not get the result but i am getting result even if condition is false.

Comment: 1) SELECT ecpclaim_key, eCPClaim_total_claim_charge 
FROM tbl_ecpclaim cl 
WHERE ecpclaim_key='1437190299'  result is 60.06

Comment: the result of your first subquery  is  SELECT SUM(ecpservicelinepaymentcobadjustment_amount) FROM tbl_ecpservicelinepaymentcobadjustment WHERE ecpservicelinepaymentcob_key = 1506453 result=9.01

Comment: 3) the result of your second subquery   SELECT SUM(eCPServiceLinePayment_Payment_Amount) FROM tbl_eCPServiceLinePayment slp WHERE slp.eCPRemit_Key = '0527416666' result is =51.05

Answer (score 1):

Let me make a wild guess here: one of the columns

```
eCPClaim_total_claim_charge
eCPServiceLinePayment_Payment_Amount
ecpservicelinepaymentcobadjustment_amount
```

is defined with the data type **float** or **real** which means you're comparing inexact floating point numbers. This would explain why `60.06 > 51.05 + 9.01` can evaluate as false which it of course shouldn't if the numbers were precise.

The remedy could be too either change the data type to an exact numeric type or to coerce the values to a precise type for the comparison.

Sample [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/aeb52/2) demonstrating the problem and a possible fix.

Answer (score 0):

It would have been a comment, if I only could :)
Regarding the first column (ecpclaim_key), you cannot have only that value or no results, since the where is explicitly asking for that:

> WHERE ecpclaim_key='1437190299'

For what concerns the second column, it is impossible to say if it is correct or not without having a complete view on the tables and their records; in any case if I was forced I would bet my 2 cents on the SQL box being right :)
It would be great if you could give us the results provided by:

```
SELECT SUM(ecpservicelinepaymentcobadjustment_amount) 
FROM tbl_ecpservicelinepaymentcobadjustment 
WHERE ecpservicelinepaymentcob_key = 1506453
```

and

```
SELECT SUM(eCPServiceLinePayment_Payment_Amount)
FROM tbl_eCPServiceLinePayment slp
WHERE slp.eCPRemit_Key = '0527416666'
```

Comment: Is there any way to over come + symbol problem

Comment: Unfortunately i do not understand which is the "+ symbol problem", could you please clarify?

Comment: You can see I have used + symbol between two columns to add two column values and make as one column after where condition .(you can + see  symbol clearly in sub query  )

Comment: for  1st query  result=9.01 and 2nd query result=51.05

Comment: I would explore the type mismatch ...